# CSS does not applied after fnDraw() jQuery Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to show hide some rows on click event on `datatable's fixed column` td img element.

Show hide works perfectly but I want to change src of that image on click.
Show hide also call function `fnDraw();`

After `fndraw()` the function `fndrawcallback` is called. but that is also not resolved the problem.

```
var currentObj=null;  
oTable = $('#frozenTable').dataTable({   
    "bPaginate": false,  
    "bFilter": false,  
    "bSort": false,  
    "sScrollY": "500px",  
    "sScrollX": "100%",  
    "sScrollXInner": "100%",  
    "bScrollCollapse": true,  
    bAutoWidth: false,  
    fixedColumns: {  
        "iLeftColumns": 3,  
        "fnDrawCallback": function () {  
        if (currentObj != null)  
            $(currentObj).find("img").attr("src", "/content/images/icons/minus.png");  
        },  
    }  
});  

// method applied on td>img element.

var ExpandCollapse = function (thisClass, obj) {  
currentObj = $(obj).closest("tr");   
thisClass = 'Channel' + thisClass;  
    if ($("." + thisClass).hasClass("hide")) {  
        $("." + thisClass).removeClass("hide");  
        var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();  
        oSettings.oScroll.sY = "400px";  
        oTable.fnDraw(false);  
    }  
    else {  
        $("." + thisClass).addClass("hide");  
    }  
};
```

the src of that image not changed.

Comment: can you place a debugger or alert inside your `fnDrawCallback` and see if its executing?

Comment: Yes by placing debugger it shows shows executing i.e. img source changes but does not reflect .

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle to reproduce the issue?